# get data from external url using php json?

Tags: php, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to extract data from an external url using json in PHP using the following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.76893497,-122.42284884&sensor=false";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
echo $json_data["formatted_address"];
?>
```

however, I get nothing on my page. in fact, i get this error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: formatted_address on line 7
```

is there something I'm missing?

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `var_dump($json)` should help you and us both :)

Comment: @Jigar, thanks, var_dump($json) prints the entire the content of the URL on my page now.

Comment: Please update your question with `var_dump($json)`'s output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'formatted_address'` is a key of the main array `'results'`, so you should loop `$json_data['results']` and search for the key `'formatted_address'`.

Comment: I tried Chandu's suggestion and still nothing being printed on my page! a blank page!

Comment: I tried that code and it works, is php configured well?

Answer (score 1):

try this way,

```
echo $json_data['results'][0]['formatted_address'];
```

Comment: still nothing! a blank page!

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing proper `INDEX`. Proper `INDEX` is `$json_data['results'][0]['formatted_address'];` for 1st result.

Use `foreach` loop to print all address.

Try

```
$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=37.76893497,-122.42284884&sensor=false";
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);

foreach($json_data['results'] as $item)
{
    echo $item['formatted_address']."<br />";
}
```